# Query all rows from a specific column Into a Table View from Bundled Sqlite DB via FMDB in SWIFT

Tags: swift, sqlite, uitableview, fmdb

I want to show all rows of a column in a table view in swift from a bundled Sqlite DB via FMDB wrapper, also I need help to show another column's data into a Text View when related row in tableView touched  . .

I've built The database and shipped it with app and designed the UI but I got stuck in querying data,

This is my first try with FMDB and unfortunately most of the FMDB tutorials are in Objective-c and not Swift . .

I think the role should be played by an array of type String .

This is all I could write for this part:

```
    var PxID = [Int]()
    var PxChapter = [String]()
    var PxContents = [String]()

    let query : String = "select Poem_Contents from DatumTestTable"
    if let rs = db.executeQuery(query, withArgumentsIn: []) {
        while rs.next() {
            let x :String = rs.string(forColumn: "Poem_Contents")!                      }
    } else {
        print("select failed: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've done everything you need to query the data. Just add each value to your array.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you but exactly that's what I can't figure out, also I need help to show another column's data into a Text View when related row in tableView TOUCHED

Comment: Just append x to PxContents. The rest of your question is far too broad.